# CLion makefile error : Error running 'Makefile': Cannot run program "\usr\bin\make" CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: makefile, clion

Running Makefile in CLion. The Makefile is of stockfish(chess) and is here https://github.com/official-stockfish/Stockfish/blob/master/src/Makefile

I am trying this on a windows 10 system.
Why is make unable to find the file? Is it a the separator issue of \ vs / on linux vs windows?

**Full error**

```
Error running 'Makefile': Cannot run program "\usr\bin\make" (in directory "C:\Users\anmol\Desktop\Coding\stockfish\src"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

My version of CLion has makefile support inbuilt and I have toolchain compilers installed via cygwin.

Answer (score 14):

The full explanation of your problem is given in [this comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-25092#focus=Comments-27-4890392.0-0) in the *JetBrains* bug tracking system.

The `Cannot run program "\usr\bin\make"` error originates from the [`Makefile` language plug-in](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9333-makefile-language) which comes bundled with *CLion* and can be added to other JetBrains' IDEs, too. Despite being bundled, the plug-in was originally a 3rd-party one and is not a part of `Makefile` support in *CLion*: to some extent, it complements the built-in support for `Makefile` projects (e. g.: by enabling syntax highlighting), but has some functionality orthogonal to that.

That "orthogonal" functionality is, particularly, the way the plug-in runs *Make* (when you click the *gutter icon* from the `Makefile` editor). This has nothing to do with *Toolchains* in *CLion* and needs to be configured separately.

### Cygwin

[image]

### MinGW

[image]

You'll need to type the full *Windows* path into the text field (e. g.: `C:\cygwin64\bin\make.exe`) and either **check** the *Use Cygwin* box (for *Cygwin*) or leave it **unchecked** (for *MinGW*).

### WSL

As of version 2022.1, the plug-in also supports running *Make* inside WSL guest VMs. See [this section](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/2022.1/makefiles-support.html#wsl-notes) in the official documentation for more details.

Following the above guidelines will enable you to invoke *Make* targets from the `Makefile` editor (using **any** *JetBrains* IDE with the plug-in installed, not just *CLion*).

Comment: Thanks! It helped me realise the problem. Unfortunately, the plugin seems to be coded in such a poor manner that it breaks if the path of make executable has whitespace in between! Likely need to submit a bug...

Answer (score 2):

Workaround:

In a CLion Makefile project, two "Configuration" types are available:
"Makefile Target" and "Makefile Application". If you edit a **"Makefile Application"** configuration, you will see a field called "Executable: "

The "Executable: " can be any Linux command including make itself. For **"Makefile Application"** (not "Makefile Target") the command is properly initiated using wsl.exe so that the command is run in WSL and not Windows.

(The problem with "Makefile Target" is obviously a CLion/plugin bug whereby "\usr\bin\make" is not run using wsl.exe, so it's run in Windows, so Windows is saying that it can't find it, which is expected because it's not supposed to be run in Windows to begin with! :-) )

Comment: I cannot find Makefile Application. Under "M" there is only "Makefile Target". Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Remove full path because in Powershell its work so

[image]